# Get the Google+ and Twitter links - Wordpress SEO plugin

Tags: user-meta

I want to use the Google+ and twitter links that can be added in User's profile using the WordPress SEO plugin and display them on the author page. Is there any way I can get those links from the plugin or do I need to fetch them using some other method say directly from database.

[SEO Plugin @the official repo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it in author.php file

Just use the following to display the Google+ and Twitter links:

```
<?php
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
echo $curauth->googleplus;
echo $curauth->twitter;
?>
```

Comment: And where does `$curauth` come from?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the $curauth.

Comment: Upvoted. Now it's a full and helpful answer :)